# Как установить python 3.10 на Linux Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, установка

Я ещё новичок в линукс, но совсем недавно скачал ubuntu. До этого сидел на Windows 10 и там проблем с последней версией python не было. Сейчас же обнаружилось, что на линуксе предустановлен python 3.8. А вот понятного объяснения как именно установить 3.10 я не нашёл. Также неразбериха возникла с официальной версией с python.org: куда именно его устанавливать после скачивания?

Comment: 1 - вам скорее всего достаточно будет и Python 3.8; 2 - на первой странице выдачи в поиске по запросу "ubuntu python 3.10": https://losst.ru/ustanovka-python-3-ubuntu (см. раздел "УСТАНОВКА PYTHON 3.10 В UBUNTU")

Comment: - "А вот понятного объяснения как именно установить 3.10" 
- Настоятельно рекомендую этого **не делать**. Большинство пришедших в люних с винды не знает (или не понимает) очень важного отличия этих двух систем. Оно заключается в том, что при установке винды Вы ставите только ОС, а забота об установке всех приложений полностью ложится на пользователя. Напротив, в люнихе существует понятие "репозитария" - т.е. хранилища ПО, которое собрано и протестировано именно и конкретно для **данного** дистрибутива. Установка ПО **не** из репозитария - гарантия кучи проблем.

Comment: Спасибо Вам, то есть лучше всего будет оставить 3.8?

Comment: @Sergey, вы часто коверкаете слово Linux, зачем вы тут?

Comment: @ReButer - "лучше всего будет оставить 3.8?" - Как правило - да. За исключением того редкого случая, когда в наиновейшей версии есть что-то такое, что Вам необходимо до зарезу, а в стандартной этой фичи ещё нет.

Comment: @0andriy  'зачем вы тут?'Где мне быть, а где мне не быть - я хочу решать сам. Если Вам не нравятся мои посты, то просто не читайте их.  Давайте в форуме по **программированию** будем говорить о программировании.

Comment: @0andriy - "вы часто коверкаете слово Linux" - А зачем Вы коверкаете слово "Тексас" ?!  Говорите неправильно "Техас" ! И слово "Мексико" тоже коверкаете - говорите "Мехико"...

Если же Вас интересует **реальное** происхождение это сленга, то могу пояснить. Первые версии BSD UNIX появились в СССР в средине 80-х годов. На их основе была выпущена "советская" ОС ДЕМОС. Программисты тех времён иронизировали, что у нас - ДЕМОС, а У НИХ - UNIX,  Позже "уних" превратился в "люних". Вот и всё...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common -y
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt install python3.10
```

Eсли не получилось,то :

```
sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev libsqlite3-dev wget libbz2-dev
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.0/Python-3.10.0.tgz
tar -xf Python-3.10.*.tgz
cd Python-3.10.*/
./configure --enable-optimizations
make -j 4
sudo make altinstall
```

Здесь вместо `install` используется `altinstall`, чтобы сохранить путь к двоичному файлу Python по умолчанию в /usr/bin/python.

Comment: Перед `sudo apt install python3.10` еще `apt update` нужно сделать

Comment: Согласен. Мой косяк ))