# Фикс пути установки python3.10 в Ubuntu23.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, apt

Пробовал поставить python3.10 на ubuntu23.04 с помощью [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1380120/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-python-3-10-%D0%BD%D0%B0-linux-ubuntu/1380171#1380171?newreg=f1bfcf2f09544d979ec5c2c2078608d9) мануала, но установился он не в /usr/bin/python3.10, а в /usr/local/bin/python3.10. Из-за этого система не видит второй поставленный python3.10 (родная версия - 3.11).

Как удалить установку из некорректной директории и поставить его корректно в нужную дирректорию?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, простите, не успел)

Comment: Что вообще значит "из-за этого система не видит второй поставленный python3.10"?

Comment: @videxerion, в пути не прописался. При штатной установке питон ставится в usr/bin, при компиляции в usr/local/bin. В первом случае его можно дернуть просто по команде python3.x. В случае с установкой в local/bin так сделать не получается. Решение проблемы - прописать новый питон в path, но я ищу решение, при котором питон будет установлен нормальным, автоматическим (да, не очень коррелируется с главным кредо системы) способом. +хотел бы понять, как денисталлировать скомпиированный питон. Способ ручного удаления папок как-то не очень внушает доверия... : )

Comment: На счёт удаление скомпилированной программы, попробуйте make uninstall в папке с исходниками.

Comment: Вообще если честно не понимаю почему же все так любят убунту? По моим наблюдениям с ней очень много проблем

Comment: @videxerion, минимальные нагрузки на железо. В случае с робототехникой оч пригождается. Но да, после винды проблем оч много.

Comment: @miku, ну вообще убунту(по крайней мере десктоп версия) очень тяжеловесна. Я бы арч поставил, ну или manjaro

Comment: Т.е. `python3.10 --version` говорит, что ничего не найдено, так?

Comment: `Вообще если честно не понимаю почему же все так любят убунту? По моим наблюдениям с ней очень много проблем` Ну вот за пакетный менеджер (не только у убунты) в том числе и любят. Кстати: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/907134/191416

Comment: `По моим наблюдениям с ней очень много проблем` а с виндой проблем меньше? Можно узнать время и количество обслуживаемых машин под виндой?

Comment: @donRumata, нет, питон не найден. Пришлось прописывать еще раз usr/local/bin в PATH, и повторно указывать альтернативы для питонов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Решил проблему](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062608/how-to-update-alternatives-to-python-3-without-breaking-apt) путем прописывания /usr/local/bin в PATH (даже при условии, что такой путь там уже числился). Плюс повторно добавил альтернативу для системного питона.

Comment: наверно, всё-таки вы добавляли абсолютный путь, а не относительный.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, хм, вроде сделал все по мануалу. Только версию питона сменил.

Comment: и что, в том руководстве, которым вы пользовались было написано «добавьте относительный путь `usr/local/bin`»? может быть, всё-таки «добавьте абсолютный путь `/usr/local/bin`»?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, выполнял следующую команду `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin`. Имею следующий вывод после `echo $PATH`: 
`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin`

Comment: ну, вот, в вашем комментарии фигурирует абсолютный путь. а в ответе — относительный. (в вопросе, кстати, тоже). похоже, вы не понимаете, что такое относительный путь и абсолютный. начните, например, с [википедийной статьи](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, благодарю за помощь!) Действительно не придал значения, когда составлял вопрос и ответ. Подразумевал абсолютный путь, как вы уже поняли. Не подумал о возможности наименования относительного пути в стиле (именами) системных папок. Сейчас поправлю. Буду внимательнее))

Comment: можно было ещё символическую ссылку добавить на требуемую версию, например
```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.10 /usr/bin/python3
```